# Custom Error page asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-config, iis-express

Im trying to make a redirect to a custom error page on Access Denied (403) and the iis express its just showing the defult ugly 403 page i made the following changes on my web.config

```
<httpErrors>
  <remove statusCode="403"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="ErrorManager/InsufcientPrivilage"/>
</httpErrors>
```

and

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="ErrorManager/InsufcientPrivilage" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorManager/PageNotFound"/>

</customErrors>
```

the strange thing is that the 404 custom error page is working but the 403 dont

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like this:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorManager/InsufcientPrivilage" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorManager/PageNotFound"/>
</customErrors>

<system.webServer> 
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

I suggest you to remove httpErrors sub elements as httpErrors are meant for displaying errors for non .net applications. In your case customErrors element is enough.

Regards,
Uros

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. (included ~/ to the beginning of redirect attribute value)

Comment: at the end i have to use the HandleUnauthorizedRequest method to do a redirect